# OBIEE EVALUATE or EVALUATE_AGGR, MAX/MIN Group By

Tags: oracle, obiee

I am trying to summarize the table in OBIEE Analysis Tool (11g) using the **EVALUATE** or **EVALUATE_AGGR** Function. I have tried using the traditional MAX and MIN without EVALUATE but due to a bug with the union functionality I am not getting the desired result.

```
    +------------------+------+-----------+----------+
    |     Loan ID      | Year |   Month   | Balance  |
    +------------------+------+-----------+----------+
    | L201618100000009 | 2021 | March     | 232,000  |
    | L201618100000009 | 2021 | June      | 232,000  |
    | L201618100000009 | 2021 | September | 232,000  |
    | L201618100000009 | 2021 | December  | 232,000  |
    +------------------+------+-----------+----------+

    EVALUATE_AGGR('MAX(%1 by %2, %3 )', "Loan and Debt Interest"."Loan BOP Amount", "Time"."Year","Loans"."Loan ID" )
```

I am getting this error: 
       `[nQSError: 10058] A general error has occurred. [nQSError: 43113] Message returned from OBIS. [nQSError: 43119] Query Failed: Please have your System Administrator look at the log for more details on this error. (HY000)`

Below is a table of what I am expecting but instead because of the UNION the traditional MAX and MIN Functions are not working. (MAX = 928K, MIN = 928K)

```
    +------------------+------+------------------+-------------------+
    |     Loan ID      | Year | (MAX)BOP Balance |  (MIN)EOP Balance |
    +------------------+------+------------------+-------------------+
    | L201618100000009 | 2021 |          232,000 |           232,000 |
    +------------------+------+------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: I don't know OBIEE; however, what UNION has to do with it? Isn't it just `select loan_id, year, max(balance), min(balance) from your_table group by loan_id, year`?

Comment: @Littlefoot OBIEE is an environment where I cannot write direct SQL. Its a friendly drag and drop UI that constructs and executes on the query on the back-end.  Your code is exactly what I am looking for but due to restrictions on the OBIEE side I am running into an issue.

Comment: I see ... oh well, I'm sorry, but I'm unable to help. Hopefully, someone else will be able to assist. Good luck!

Comment: Can't say I am familiar with the union bug, but I have used the `evaluate` function, though not very proud of using it (see it as a last resort.... and not a good one at that).  What error are you getting with your use of `evaluate_aggr`?

Comment: @PatrickBacon After a few hours on google it does seem that people use evaluate as a last resort. `[nQSError: 10058] A general error has occurred. [nQSError: 43113] Message returned from OBIS. [nQSError: 43119] Query Failed: Please have your System Administrator look at the log for more details on this error. (HY000)` is the error

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by the recent (re-)increase of questions like "I want to do this SQL in OBI". That's not how the tool works. That's not how it is designed.

a) If you are forced to do UNION requests, then your data model is poor to begin with.

b) You can easily create a level-based measure in the RPD which is tied to the year level of your time hierarchy and then set the aggregation rule to MAX. Same for MIN. That requires a proper data model though.

c) In the analysis you can also create a new calculated column using MAX("Balance" by "Loan ID", "Year") and it will also give you the same result.

Comment: Hey Chris, thank you for your feedback. (a) I agree with you, but as an analyst remodeling the subject area isn't fiesable without a lengthy dev cycle. (b) I agree, but it is all about how the data is modeled, which is out of my control. (c) I will give the new calculated column a try.